# Декодирование строки Utf-8 (hex.) в читабельный вид

Tags: hex, utf-8, c++

Имеется строка вида

```
"=D1=80=D1=83=D1=81=D1=81=D0=BA=D0= =B8=D0=B9;=D0=90=D0=B9=D0=B7=D0=B5=D1=80-=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=BA"
```

Как полагаю, это utf-8 (hex.).
Как и чем (C++), вот это декодировать в нормальный читабельный вид?
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Ну если совсем без проверок (просто быстро написать, чтобы один раз прочесть), то можно так

```
#include <stdio.h>

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
   char text[10000], *t = text, *p;
   int  n;

   for (p = av[1]; *p; p++) {
     if (*p == '=') {
       sscanf(p+1,"%x",&n);
       *t++ = n;
       p += 2;
     } else {
       *t++ = *p;
     }
   }
   *t = 0;
   printf ("%s\n",text);
   return 0;
}
```

У меня получилось:

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc thex.c 
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out '=D1=80=D1=83=D1=81=D1=81=D0=BA=D0=B8=D0=B9;=D0=90=D0=B9=D0=B7=D0=B5=D1=80-=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=BA'
русский;Айзер-как
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

Comment: Не могли бы пояснить как это сделано... Я в синтаксисе C не особо силен. Но в любом случае, уже Спасибо!

Comment: @Гера, надо изучить. Рекомендую Б.Керниган, Д.Ритчи "Язык программирования С".

А что, собственно, тут непонятно?

Берем закодированный текст из первого аргумента программы. Если очередной символ это `=`, то *предполагая* (по хорошему это проверять надо), что дальше две 16-ричные цифры (код байта символа в utf-8) читаем их (как число) в переменную `n` и записываем ее (младший байт) выходную строку.

Иначе просто копируем байт входа на выход.

Переходим к очередному символу входа. Если был `=`, то на 3 байта вперед, иначе на один.

Понятно?

Answer (score 0):

Нет. это не utf-8/hex как вы его назвали. такой метод кодирования строк применяется по большей части в почтовых сервисах при кодировании письма (RFC822 и старше). данная "кодировка" имеет название quoted-printable и не обязательно что там окажется utf-8 кодировка... как ее декодировать на плюсах я вам не подскажу, но направление куда капать я вам указал.

Comment: судя по данным это таки UTF-8 в QP. только данные битые.
http://www.webatic.com/run/convert/qp.php

Comment: Ну да, вы правы. "CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE".
Но, как я в итоге разобрался, каждые две группы "=D1=80" соответствую символу utf-8 ("=D1=80" вот это, к примеру соответствует русской "р" в utf-8 это U+0440). я не понимаю как это причести к читабельному виду программно.

Comment: куском кода на Python я вам сильне не помогу но все же может хоть какую-то точку опоры для размышлений дам.  
import re  
msg ="=D1=80=D1=83=D1=81=D1=81=D0=BA=D0=B8=D0=B9;=D0=90=D0=B9=D0=B7=D0=B5=D1=80-=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=BA"  
r=''  
lst=list(set(re.findall(r'(=[A-F0-9]{2})',msg)))  
for i in lst:  
    msg=msg.replace(i,chr(eval(i.replace('=','0x'))))  
print msg